# Logging using @Loggable jcabi annotations trims the logs

Tags: java, log4j, jcabi

I am annotating my function @Loggable jcabi annotation. 
The statement it logs is not complete, it trims the line and just prints .. for the truncated data.
I want the entire line to be printed. Can this be done with this annotation.

```
@Loggable(Loggable.DEBUG)
public String load(URL url) {
  return url.openConnection().getContent();
}
```

Produces the following log

```
[DEBUG] #load('http://www.google.com'): returned "<html ..." in 23ms
```

Log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file, CONSOLE

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=swami-plugin.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=com.jcabi.log.MulticolorLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%color{%-5p}] %c: %m%n
```

Comment: Are you using `log4j` for `slf4j` bindings?

Comment: I am using log4j binding

Comment: Could you please provide `log4j.xml` or `log4.properties` settings, particularly I'm interested in `layout` stuff. The issue seems to be there.

Comment: Updated the question with properties

Comment: `CONSOLE` layout has the same settings?

Comment: Edited the question with settings. Appreciate your time in helping me

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25591/discussion-between-nandish-a-and-n1ckolas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. [`@Loggable`](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-loggable.html) annotation outputs method parameter and result object by using their `toString()` methods of up to 100 characters. Mostly in order to keep log lines short enough to fit into syslog and similar systems.

Maybe it would be good to add an optional parameter to disable that trimming feature:

```
@Loggable(trim = false)
public String load(URL url) {
```

I would recommend to submit a request [in github](https://github.com/yegor256/jcabi).

Comment: Should I fork the project, do the change and submit the pull request?

Comment: Will the maven repository be updated with this latest version? 0.7.9 is the latest on maven repository

Comment: Thank you so much and we appreciate for the swift response in implementing this. I was referring to http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jcabi/jcabi-aspects. Anyways I got the latest version and works like a charm . Thank you once again.